# symfony 3 - how to add a eventsubscriber as a service in a form

Tags: forms, symfony, events, service, listener

In my application, I created a listener for onPostSubmit event in forms.
I created a new class that implement EventSubscriberInterface.
In the builderForm I added the evnet subscriber like this :
`->addEventSubscriber(new MyNewListener())`

Everything is working well, but not as I would like...

In my listener, I need the entity manager to query the database.

The first solution I have found is to add the entity manager in the form via the options and pass it to the listener via the constructor. The code is now :
`->addEventSubscriber(new MyNewListener($options['entity_manager']))`

This solution works but I don't want to use it like this, I prefer to use a service and add the entity manager in the service definition.

Then, my question is: How to declare the listener as a service (and pass the entity manager) and how to call it in the form declaration ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Make your form type a service and then inject the listener into it.  The form factory knows about the container and will pull the form type from it based on the class name.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_dependencies.html#define-your-form-as-a-service

Answer (score 2):

Just treat your subscriber as a service.

Yml configuration. You can spare `autowire:true` if you have all classes autowired:

```
services:
    My\Form\Type:
        autowire: true
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }

    My\Form\Listener\MyNewListener:
        autowire: true
```

Form class:

```
...

class MyForm extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var MyNewListener
     */
    private $listener;

    /**
     * @param MyNewListener $listener
     */
    public function __construct(MyNewListener $listener)
    {
        $this->listener = $listener;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        ...
        $builder->addEventSubscriber($this->listener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your form as a service in the container, like Cerad mentioned in his comment.

Since you are using Symfony 3 you can either choose to configure the service with `autowire: true`, or manually declare your arguments. Then inside your FormType you can pass those class properties to your Subscriber class. When you define your form as a service, be sure to tag it with `form.type`. Here is example code below.

Services.yml

```
services:
    your.form.type:
        class: EventsBundle\Form\MarketerType
        autowire: true # this is not needed if using arguments
        arguments: [ '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager' ] # this is not needed if using autowire
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

FormType.php

```
<?php

namespace EventsBundle\Form;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
...

class FormType extends AbstractType
{
    /** @var EntityManager */
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        ...
        $builder->addEventSubscriber(new YourNewListener($this->em));
    }
    ...
```

Then, to be on the safe side, you'll want to clear the application cache. I hope this helps!